# Playonlinux/Wine: How to add directories for quick access

Tags: wine, playonlinux, workflow

I would like to add some of my directories in /home to the quick access directories in e.g. Word. In windows it would do a simple drag and drop within the opening/saving dialogue. But that does not work here.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible, and no worries, it's not at all technical! With a Word document open, perform the following steps.

1. Open the save dialog box.
2. Navigate to the folder you want to add
3. Right-Click in the left "places" pane and add the directory you're viewing.

That's it. I've included a demo below that you can click to enlarge. If you have slow Internet access, give it a second. It's about 1M to load.
[image: demo.gif]